# Move an enemy on top of a moving platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a setup which involves a moving platform(in green) and a patrolling enemy on top of it, shown below:

[image]

The platform is moving left and right, periodically and so is the patrolling enemy both using `rigidbody.velocity`. Both when in motion separately are appearing fine. But when enemy is on the top of the platform, with enemy being the childobject of platform, the enemy is appearing static (just playing moving animation in it's place) even though I have corrected for the velocity of the platform. Below is the snippet of my code for patrolling enemy:

```
void Start()
    {
        myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        parent = transform.parent;
        parentVelocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (parent != null && parent.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null) 
            parentVelocity = parent.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;

        Debug.Log("parentVelocity=== " + parentVelocity);
        if (IsFacingRightOrUp())
        {
            if (moveVertical)
                myVelocity = new Vector2(0f, moveSpeed);
            else
                myVelocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (moveVertical)
                myVelocity = new Vector2(0f, -moveSpeed);
            else
                myVelocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0f);            
        }
        Debug.Log("myRigidBody.velocity === " + myVelocity);
        myRigidBody.velocity = myVelocity + parentVelocity;
        Debug.Log("myRigidBody.velocity === " + myRigidBody.velocity);
    }
```

It is producing the Debug logs as follows, `parentVelocity` being defaulted to (0,0):

[image]

What should I do to make the motion of enemy same to an observer on the platform as the motion of enemy would appear when both are standing on the static ground?

The correction applied using `myRigidBody.velocity = myVelocity + parentVelocity;` doesn't seem to matter at all. The enemy is appearing static regardless of correction. And if I change the velocity of moving platform to zero, it is working as expected. Why is the relative velocity correction not working?

Even if I hardcore the velocity to 100, then also the enemy is appearing to be static, although the rigidbody component correctly displays the velocity as 100.

Comment: From your code I can see that logs should look like  
`parentVelocity=== ValueOfparentVelocity`, 
`myRigidBody.velocity === ValueOfmyVelocity`,   
`myRigidBody.velocity === ValueOfmyRigidBody.velocity`.   
However in your logs I can see that you are missing some of
`myRigidBody.velocity === `
Maybe your code crashes silently (without throwing exception)? Did you try to debug it step by step? I'd recommend you doing this :-)

Comment: would the use of "relative velocity" be relevant? https://answers.unity.com/questions/1161764/what-exactly-is-relativevelocity.html

Comment: also https://answers.unity.com/questions/12083/how-to-get-a-character-to-move-with-a-moving-platf.html
If your enemy is a child of the platform it should just work fine, unless the movement of this object is done in a wrong way. 
You can consider this tutorial https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/s/2d-game-kit

Comment: @Paradowski i updated to show you the count of logs as well. the ones highlighted in blue is when the platform is moving to left with velocity of 1, and the one in yellow is when the platform is moving right with velocity of 1. platform is moving at velocity of 1 all the time, just changing direction periodically.

Comment: @Nerevar relative velocity is what I am trying to achieve by finding the speed of parent and adding it to the child. Also, I stated above that the platform is parent of enemy, which is mentioned in the link that you posted above.

Comment: @vipin8169 I mean you don't have to calculate it if they are in contact, unity does it for you https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html

Comment: One last thing from unity documentation itself, it is not recommended to set/modify velocity as it would lead to unrealistic behaviour, especially if you have many animations/objects interacting with eachother https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: @Nerevar while trying to make it work, I first made the enemy as child of platform hoping that it would work. Only after realizing that it doesn't work i applied the velocity correction. FYI, the platform is created using tilemap as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cbAy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `transform.Translate(myVelocity * Time.deltaTime);` without relative velocity correction fixed this, though I do not fully understand why.

```
void Update()
{        
    if (IsFacingRightOrUp())
    {
        if (moveVertical)
            myVelocity = new Vector2(0f, moveSpeed);
        else
            myVelocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0f);
    }
    else
    {
        if (moveVertical)
            myVelocity = new Vector2(0f, -moveSpeed);
        else
            myVelocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0f);            
    }                
    myRigidBody.velocity = myVelocity;
    transform.Translate(myVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

[image]